# Unable to bind local var to nested global var

Tags: python

Unable to bind the local `x` of `f()` to the global var `x` of the nested `g()`. Why?

```
def f():
 x=0
 def g():
  global x
  x+=1
  print(x)
 g()
 g() # added to make seemingly more practical
```

-

```
>>> f()
...
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: `x` is not a global variable, it is local to the function `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make `x` a global variable in function `f()`:

```
def f():
    global x
    x = 0
    def g():
        global x
        x += 1
        print(x)
    g()

f()
# 1
```

---

As mentioned in comment, the 'global' state of `x` is pointless here, so it's better you pass `x` as argument to `g()` like so:

```
def f():
    x = 0
    def g(x):
        x += 1
        print(x)
    g(x)

f()
# 1
```

This not only makes your code more concise but also removes the overhead of 'global's.

Comment: One should mention, however, that the global variable in this code is utterly pointless. This function will always print `1`, no matter the "global" state of `x`

Comment: i also think it's genraly good practice not to use global, unless it's necesary

Comment: @JonasWolff Ofcourse. Here is more details to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using globals, simply pass a parameter through the function `g`:

```
def f():
    x=0
    def g(y):
        y+=1
        print(y)
    g(x)

f()
```

This should work.